# how remove object of the matched req.params.id

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

```js
router.delete('/shopping-cart/:id', (req, res) => {
    let cart = new Cart(req.session.cart);
    console.log(req.params.id);
    console.log(cart.generateArray());
});
```

console.log(cart.generateArray()) outputs follow result

```
[{
  item:
    {
      _id: '5c863cc8ee0819f989acf9c3',
      imagePath: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png',
      title: 'Gothic Video',
      description: 'Absolutely stunning',
      price: 10,
      __v: 0
    },
  image: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/5/5e/Gothiccover.png',
  qty: 1,
  price: 10,
  id: '5c863cc8ee0819f989acf9c3'
}]
```

console.log will output the following result (req.params.id):

```
5c863cc8ee0819f989acf9c3
```

Everytime when user clicks on the close button it should call this delete method and remove the entire corresponding object. And then output an updated list on the client server side. Anyone who could point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the filter-function to remove an item of a list:

```
const newList = currentList.filter(element => element.id !== id);
```

That's it. The newList only contains elements that don't have the matching id. The object with the matching id gets dropped.

EDIT: Here is one way how to check whether the id actually matches:

```
console.log('matching object: ', currentList.filter(element => element.id === id)[0]);
```

Comment: when I console log out 'newlist.length' i still get the same length constantly. Seems the item would not be removed in this case.

Comment: Sorry, but this is one of the most common use cases of filter. Can you make sure that the id you compare against actually exists in one of the objects?